# WebSocket in Spring Boot app Could not autowire error

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that I want to handle both rest calls and websockets. In my RestController I am able to define an instance of my GameUnitService as autowired, and it works as expected. ie: Gets populated and I can use it.

```
@Autowired private GameUnitService gameUnitService;
```

But when I try to autowire the above service in my websocket config, I get the error *Could not autowire. No beans of 'GameUnitService' type found.*. No error on the ApplicationContext.

However when I run the app after I remove the autowired from GameUnitService, the appContext is null when McpWebSocketConfig gets constructed.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class McpWebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(McpWebSocketConfig.class);

    @Autowired private GameUnitService gameUnitService;  //error: Could not autowire
    @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;    //this will end up null

    public McpWebSocketConfig() {
        //appContext is null
    }
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new McpWebSocketHandler(), "/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addHandler(new McpWebSocketHandler(), "/").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
```

I had also tried moving the GameUnitService into the handler, and while the bean error was no longer present, the gameUnitService is null.

```
public class McpWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {
    @Autowired
    private GameUnitService gameUnitService;

    public McpWebSocketHandler() {
        // gameUnitService is null
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the bean (*You will need the bean of GameUnitService for Autowire*), you need to enable the behavior to scan your classpath which spring does not do by default.

**@ComponentScan** is the annotation to scan for components declared in your code . by default, **@ComponentScan** only scans the package and all the sub-packages of its annotated class.
This means you need to tell the **@ComponentScan** to scan different packages,
preferably your root package .

So you will need an additional annotation.

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ApplicationLauncher.class)
```

`ApplicationLauncher is the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication`

Change your configuration class to read like so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ApplicationLauncher.class)
public class McpWebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(McpWebSocketConfig.class);

    @Autowired private GameUnitService gameUnitService;  //error: Could not autowire
    @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;    //this will end up null

    public McpWebSocketConfig() {
        //appContext is null
    }
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new McpWebSocketHandler(), "/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addHandler(new McpWebSocketHandler(), "/").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
```